# How do I get the mirror of the first element of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, mirror

I need to input numbers into an array, get the first number, mirror it, and then see if any other numbers in said array are the same as the mirror.

Example: 4 numbers, 123 321 111 and 200; the mirror of 123 is 321, so it should tell me "Yes", since there is 1 more element in the array that is the same as the mirror.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    int n = 0, mirror, cnt = 0;
    int* v = new int[n];
    
    cout << "How many elements?\n";
    cin >> n;
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];
    
    while(v[0] != 0){
        mirror = mirror * 10 + v[0] % 10;
        v[0] /= 10;
    }
    cout << mirror;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(v[i] == mirror && v[i] != v[0])
            cnt++;
    if(cnt >=1)
        cout << "Yes";
    else
        cout << "No";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on _all_ of your compilers warnings, `mirror` is used uninitialized, your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: I suggest you write functions such as `int getMirror(int num)`, so that you aren't cramming everything in `main`, causing the issue that is mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @churill my compiler didn't say anything about the mirror being uninitialized, but maybe I didn't pay attention.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't write such functions because we didn't learn them in school and I don't have enough practice with them to be comfortable using those

Comment: And once you do that: `int cnt = std::count_if(v + 1, v + n, [](int value) { return value == mirror_value; });` -- Making those `for` loops unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Even shorter: `int cnt = std::count(v + 1, v + n, mirror);`

Comment: I suggest you write `std::optional<int> tryGetMirror(int num)` because some ints presumably don't have a well-defined mirror: like negative numbers (because you haven't defined how to treat the minus sign), and some 10-digit ints where the mirror would overflow the int.  Two undefined values are presumably not to be treated as equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major problems in your code. First, you are attempting to allocate your `v` array **before** you know the user's input value of `n`; this can be fixed by moving the declaration/allocation of `v` to *after* the `cin >> n;` line.

Second, you never give the `mirror` variable an initial (zero) value, so it could start out as anything, which you then add the digits' values to in your `while` loop.

Here's a fixed version of your code, with comments on the changed lines:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, mirror = 0, cnt = 0; // MUST initialize "mirror"

    cout << "How many elements?\n";
    cin >> n;
    int* v = new int[n]; // CAN ONLY allocate the array AFTER we have input the value of "n"

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> v[i];

    while (v[0] != 0) {
        mirror = mirror * 10 + v[0] % 10;
        v[0] /= 10;
    }
    cout << mirror;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (v[i] == mirror && v[i] != v[0])
            cnt++;
    if (cnt >= 1)
        cout << "Yes";
    else
        cout << "No";

    delete[] v; // For good coding style, don't forget to deallocate the array!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, although I don't understand why in other programs I made, i put the `int* v = new int[n]` before the `cin >> n` and it still worked flawlessly
Also i will try to implement the `delete[] v` thing you showed me from now on, looks like a good idea :D

Comment: @MickeyMoise Not sure what 'other programs' you mean. But, I believe there are some **other languages** in which such an order could work; not sure, though.

Comment: @MickeyMoise I'm pretty confident to say that it couldn't work flawlessly. Allocating an array of size 0 and writing and reading out of bounds is undefined behaviour, so it might appear to work.

Comment: *and it still worked flawlessly* -- No it didn't work.  You were just lucky.

Comment: I mean other applications, not other languages, other array exercises I've been doing

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Some might argue that was **un**lucky! ‎

Comment: @MickeyMoise -- Undefined behavior.  C++ allows you to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of swapping bytes in integers, why don't you convert each number to a C string using itoa() and then use strrev() to reverse the string?
Then you can compare the strings with strcmp(). Lesser code, also more understandable and less error-prone.

Comment: What is strcmp(). I do not know this function in C++.

Comment: strcmp ==  (C) string compare. Standard C function